# Using Times New Roman in eps images with psfrag

Tags: fonts, eps, psfrag

I'm using the `chemstyle` package to produce chemical reaction schemes.  It uses the `psfrag` package to replace placeholders in eps graphics with numbers for molecules.  I'm trying to use Times New Roman font in these eps files (not for the placeholders, but for other text), but LaTeX doesn't seem to like it:

```
### /usr/texbin/dvips -R -Poutline  -o /tmp/altpdflatex.31054-1317561093/Thesis.ps Thesis.dvi This is dvips(k) 5.97 Copyright 2008 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2011.10.03:0011' -> /tmp/altpdflatex.31054-1317561093/Thesis.ps /usr/texbin/dvips: ! Couldn't find header file times.pfb. Note that an absolute path or a relative path with .. are denied in -R2 mode.
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.31054-1317561093/Thesis.ps ()
```

Is it possible to fix this, using LaTeX rather than pdfLaTeX?  Where might I find such a header file?

Edit:  The Times New Roman text was added in ChemDraw.  The eps in question is a chemical scheme, so I draw these in ChemDraw, sometimes with additional text.  I'd like that text to match the font I'm using for LaTeX (TNR).

Edit2: An example eps: http://www.2shared.com/file/upfvXkpS/Test.html

Comment: Just realised this is a dvips problem, not a latex problem.  Is there a workaround (I don't want to use pdflatex)...

Comment: So the Times New Roman text is within the image itself due to some non-LaTeX application?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. For non-LaTeX code, such as your error message, the `<pre>` markup works best. Also, we tend to avoid greetings and closings in posts to keep things concise.

Comment: I suspect we're going to need to see the `.eps` file in question. Is there somewhere you could make it available so we can have a look? It might also be a good idea to describe how you made it.

Comment: The `times.pfb` bit is what puzzles me: there's no such font file in TeX Live or other distributions. What should be used is `ptmr8a.pfb`.

Comment: The EPS file is not sufficient. One has to know how you use psfrag on it.

Answer (score 1):

(More of an extended comment)

For me, this works fine using TeX Live 2011 on Windows 7.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,chemscheme}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My demo file builds as expected using `pdlatex` or `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.  As egreg says, to say more we'll need an example of what you are doing.

(As an aside, I would urge against using a serif font in your schemes and figures. Sticking to sans serif looks much better for these: see any of the common journal templates.)